# SQL Server Order By Column having Inch Sizes

Tags: sql-server

I have column in database with inch sizes - for example

```
1", 3/4", 15/16", 5/8" etc
```

So when I run query let's say

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB_Items 
ORDER BY Size ASC
```

it returns:

```
 1", 5/8" , 3/4" , 15/16"
```

but I need

```
5/8", 3/4", 15/16", 1"
```

Please help

Note: `Size` column datatype is `varchar`

Answer (score 1):

Add more sizes as you need them

```
..ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN inch_col = "5/8" THEN 1
 WHEN inch_col = "3/4" THEN 2
 WHEN inch_col = "15/16" THEN 3
 WHEN inch_col = "1" THEN 4
 ELSE 5 END
```

Answer (score 1):

If sizes <= 1" you can use relatively complex expression to sort result set. The better way to create calculated persisted column. If sizes > 1 sort expression is much more complicated

```
create table Item
(
    Id int not null identity primary key,
    Size varchar(100) not null
)
go

insert into Item (Size)
    values ('1"'), ('3/4"'), ('15/16"'), ('5/8"');
go

select 
    id, size
from 
    Item
order by
    CAST((CASE CHARINDEX('/', Size) WHEN 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Size, 1, LEN(Size) - 1) ELSE SUBSTRING(Size, 1, CHARINDEX('/', Size) - 1) END) as DECIMAL(18, 4)) /
    CASE CHARINDEX('/', Size) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(Size, CHARINDEX('/', Size) + 1, LEN(Size) - CHARINDEX('/', Size) - 1) as INT) END
```